# Wildcard Sub-Domain Setup

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wildcard-subdomain

This works for rewriting all requests to the *index.php* located in my root folder, which works for example.com/1/2/3/4/5/...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.mallzones\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I am trying to figure how to rewrite the wildcard subdomains as well. The wildcard should be prepended to the path. How do I modify these rules to accomplish the following url scheme.

*example.com/1/* **is equal to** *1.example.com*

*example.com/1/2* **is equal to** *1.example.com/2*

*example.com/1/2/3* **is equal to** *1.example.com/2/3*

*example.com/1/2/3/4* **is equal to** *1.example.com/2/3/4*

I've already created the A record in my DNS zones. What do I do next?

ANSWER: kudos to **@CRIMSON 501**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me understand. Are you asking how to make it so that when a user navigates to **example.com/1/** they are rerouted to **1.example.com**?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

To have a silent redirect the last line should be:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/or/whatever/you/need [L]
```

Just edit the links to what you need!

Comment: You were right. With your knowledge, I figured out the silent redirect I was looking for. Take a look at the edit.